# Error web debug toolbar

Tags: php, symfony, symfony1

I have recently upgraded the Ubuntu OS (10.04 -> 12.04) in my development workstation, and know I'm getting trouble in running the project I'm working on. I think it's some permission related problem. The fact is that I already have it running with no problems in a production server.

Is there any tool I can check project's folder permissions for errors, more or less like "**symfony project:permissions**" in Symfony 1 ?

I'm getting a css troubled first page in my dev frontend and a JS alert that reads:

```
An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (404: Not Found). Do you want to open the profiler?
```

The web folder **.htacess** is the same from the working production environment and I have an apache configuration equal to production only with ssl disabled.

**Edit:**

Virtual Host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    #<Directory />
    #       Options FollowSymLinks
    #       AllowOverride None
    #</Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            AcceptPathInfo On
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /myproject /home/nelson/des/php/myproject/Symfony/web

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The "AcceptPathInfo On" was included in an attempt to solve. I already tried with and without it.

Any help apreciated

Comment: The *"SO"*? What's that?

Comment: ups... mixing portuguese and english :D sorry. Edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you haven't published your assets (css, js, images...)

Try the following from command line in the root folder of Symfony :

```
php app/console assets:install web/ --symlink
```

Also, check that the rewrite mod is enabled : `a2enmod rewrite`

**EDIT:** Given your VirtualHost config file, it seems that you gave the wrong folder to Apache. You configuration must point to the `web` folder of Symfony2. For example :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/myuser/www/Symfony/web
    <Directory /home/myuser/www/Symfony/web>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    #......
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: tried, nops... not that. I had tried that command before but without the "web/ --symlink" part.

Comment: Have you checked that the rewrite mod is enabled ? `a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: well I had checked, but not that way. I had checked using phpinfo(). And phpinfo() says it's enabled. But when I use the command you mentioned I got the following response:
    
-sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
-sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
-sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
-Module rewrite already enabled
    
Does the messages that say "no such file" mean anything ?

Comment: It happens when your terminal is on a directory that doesn't exist anymore - not a big deal. Try to get a clean .htaccess if you modified it previously. You can also try to update Apache (`apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get upgrade`). If it doesn't work, give your VirtualHost configuration.

Comment: First, thanks for your help.
Well I modified .htaccess but restore it and tried without it. Can't update apache's version, because it's the same as my production server version and before the OS upgrade it was working fine. Updated the question to include virtualhost configuration.

Comment: Check my edited answer. Even if you use an alias to `/home/nelson/des/php/myproject/Symfony/web`, you are not giving rights to Apache for this folder.